# Как сделать редирект на главный страницу, тобишь на главный html файл?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот код html с кнопкой:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>

    <title>Регистрация</title>

    <script src='./js/script.js'></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <form>

        <div class='group'>
            <center><button id="addButton">Registration</button></center>
        </div>
        
    </form>
            
</body>

</html>
```

Вот код js:

```
(function (window, document) {
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
        var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        button.onclick = handleButtonClick; 
}
    function handleButtonClick() {
        location = "main.html"; 
}
})(window, document);
```

Файл `index.html` который содержит форму регистрации и кнопку, после нажатия на кнопку должен редиректить на файл `main.html`, который так же расположен в папке с `index.html`, но js скрипт почему то не работает. Если заменить `location = 'main.html';` на `alert('123');` то после нажатия на кнопку почему то все работает, помогите исправить данную проблему, буду благодарен, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно отменить дефолтный обработчик формы.

```
(function (window, document) {
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
      var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
      button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    }
    function handleButtonClick(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      location.href = 'main.html'
    }
  })(window, document);
```

Comment: Теперь кнопка вообще не нажимается

Comment: Все нажимается, вы где то допустили ошибку когда составляли сам документ. Проверил лично.

Answer (score 1):

По нажатию на кнопку происходит отправка формы и перезагрузка страницы. Сделайте как в ответе @ВадимАлександру или:

```
<button type="button" id="addButton">Registration</button>
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить `location = "main.html";` на `location.href = "main.html";`

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: А если ```window.location.href```?

Comment: Так тоже не работает

Comment: В html файле измените строку  ```<center><button id="addButton">Registration</button></center>```
на 
 ```<center><button onclick="location.href='main.html'">Registration</button></center>```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.assign('/main.html')
```

— так попробуй

Comment: Куда прописывать здесь название файла на который редиректить

Comment: если тебе нужна главная - так и прописывай

Comment: Смотрите, допустим в файле с кнопкой находиться форма регистрации, после нажатия на кнопку должен открываться другой html файл с разметкой главной страницы, как можно это осуществить

Comment: переписал - пробуй

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: путь указываешь верно к файлу ? или вообще никуда не перебрасывает ?

Comment: Два html файла лежат в одной папке, js файл лежит в папке которая находиться с файлами html, так как файлы лежать в одной папке я указываю просто название `main.html`

Comment: Ничего не происходит кроме обновления страницы регистрации

Comment: еще один :) Справка -> Как публиковать ответы -> -> Как написать хороший ответ? -> `Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. `